Insert "and" before last author name using natbib.sty
I need to insert , and before the last author name, for this, I'm trying with the codes:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[comma,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{foo,
author={Foo},
year={2016},
Title={Foo foo}
}
@article{bar,
author={Bar},
year={2014},
Title={Bar bar}
}
@article{tilde,
author={Tilde},
year={2015},
Title={Tilde tilde}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\NAT@inline@cnt
\preto\NAT@reset@citea{%
    \NAT@inline@cnt=\@ne
    \mathchardef\NAT@total@cnt=\count@
}
\def\NAT@separator{%
    \advance\NAT@inline@cnt\@ne
    \ifnum\NAT@inline@cnt=\NAT@total@cnt
        \ifnum\NAT@inline@cnt=\tw@\else
            \NAT@sep\NAT@penalty
        \fi
        \NAT@space and%
    \else
        \NAT@sep\NAT@penalty
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citet{foo,bar,tilde} are nuts.  \citet{foo,bar} are in fact insane.

\bibliography{foo}

\end{document}

Thanks to natbib and \citet: inserting `and' after the last semicolon, but if I remove the option sort, then the desired output doesn't come correctly, please advise.
